# Get the project path/output path during Postsharp compile time

Tags: postsharp

Is it possible to find out the project folder/project file or output path of the assembly during compile time in Postsharp, i.e. during CompileTimeInitialize for example, when the assembly is being built?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out the path to the current project file by evaluating the 'MSBuildProjectFullPath' property during compile time:

```
public override void CompileTimeInitialize(MethodBase method, AspectInfo aspectInfo)
{
    string projectPath =
        PostSharpEnvironment.CurrentProject
            .EvaluateExpression("{$MSBuildProjectFullPath}");
}
```

The list of some other PostSharp properties can be found on this [documentation page](http://doc.postsharp.net/configuration-msbuild).